# Jquery .eq plus contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

When trying to get from all [tr] the second [td] that contains some information, i keep getting stuck on logic. Here is some example.

```
<table class="todos">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>info1</td>
      <td>info2</td>
      <td>info3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the Javascript to find it for me...

```
$(".todos tbody tr").css('display','none');
$(".todos tbody tr").each(function(){
    if($(this).find("td:eq(0):contains("+procurar+")"))
        $(this).css('display','table-row');
    if($(this).find("td:eq(1):contains("+procurar+")"))
        $(this).css('display','table-row');
});
```

Comment: First you have a missing `)`. Second, you are checking an object, of course it will always be true.

Comment: `:contains` does not return `true/false` but the object itself, if that contains the value given in `contains`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hiding the parent `tr`, so setting another display property on the `td`'s won't show them, but if that's not the intended functionality, I'd do:

```
$(".todos tbody tr").hide().find('td:lt(2)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(procurar) != -1;
}).closest('tr').css('display','table-row');
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to display the `tr` that contain such cells. This code is ultimately setting `display: table-row` to `td` elements that pass the `filter()`. I think making it `.closest('tr').css('display','table-row');` after `filter()` will make it work.

Comment: @Ejay - I'll add that, as it does seem strange to hide the parent, and then set the display property on it's children, which of course would be hidden ?

Comment: @adeneo, look carefully to my code, im not setting the display of the TD table-row, im setting the display of the TR. The only thing that is missing is a ) at the and, and i'm sorry for that.

Comment: @LuizFelipeKale - Yeah, see it now, just strange use of selectors, sorry! Anyway, edited answer should do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a syntax error in first `if` condition and some faulty code near `:contains`

This one might work for you

```
        var procurar = 'info2';
        $(".todos tr").css('display', 'none');
        $(".todos tbody tr").each(function () {
           if($(this).find('td:lt(2):contains("' + procurar + '")').length){
              $(this).css('display', 'table-row');
           }
        });
```

Comment: Your code seems more like to be a solution. Altough it is still not working for me. I've already used a function to replace the :contains method to be Case Insensitive. If you'd like to see the page online, its here: http://rj.asdner.org.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=104&buscar=aba This should list all the names having ABA on the td.

Comment: great to know that you've found the solution. The above code makes a `tr` element `display: table-row` if its 1st or 2nd column contains `procurar` variable. Does it act differently for you? Asking to make it useful for future readers

Comment: Nope, your lt can be used in this.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see all of your code (Example: I don't know what `procurar` is equal to), I set up a little sample with some hard coded values that works:

JavaScript

```
$(".todos tbody tr").each(function() {
    var $targetTDs = $(this).find("td:contains('info1')");

    if ($targetTDs.length > 1) {
        var $theSecondInstanceOfATDContainingInfo1 = $targetTDs[1];
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="todos">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>info1</td>
            <td>info1</td>   // $theSecondInstanceOfATDContainingInfo1 is this one
            <td>info2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info1</td>
            <td>info2</td>
            <td>info1</td>   // $theSecondInstanceOfATDContainingInfo1 is this one
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info2</td>
            <td>info1</td>
            <td>info1</td>   // $theSecondInstanceOfATDContainingInfo1 is this one
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For each row that contains two TDs that have the value `info1`, `$theSecondInstanceOfATDContainingInfo1` will capture the second TD.

From your original code, I can't tell if you actually need the matched TD or if you just need to know that it exists, but you could adapt this code to handle either case.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you want to get the [tr]s that have at least 2 [td]s containing some information you should use :contains before :lt.

HTML

```
<table class="todos">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>info1</td>
            <td>info2</td>
            <td>info3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info1</td>
            <td>other</td>
            <td>info3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info1</td>
            <td>other</td>
            <td>some other</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var procurar = 'info';
$(".todos tr").css('display', 'none');
$(".todos tbody tr").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('td:contains("' + procurar + '"):lt(2)').length > 1) {
        $(this).css('display', 'table-row');
    }
});
```

Result:

```
info1   info2   info3
info1   other   info3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Sj7t

**Else**, if you want to get the [tr]s whose 2nd [td] contains some information you should use :lt before :contains, as in your example.

HTML

```
<table class="todos">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>info1</td>
        <td>info2</td>
        <td>other</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>info1</td>
        <td>other</td>
        <td>info2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS:

```
var procurar = 'info';
$(".todos tr").css('display', 'none');
$(".todos tbody tr").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('td:lt(2):contains("' + procurar + '")').length > 1) {
        $(this).css('display', 'table-row');
    }
});
```

Result:

```
info1   info2   other
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Sj7t/1/